# TranslatePress plugin throwing errors after site migration to the new server

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

So I am migrating a WordPress site to another server and on the new server the [TranslatePress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/translatepress-multilingual/) plugin gives this error:

> PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 4 in C:\WebSites\wwwroot\scas_new\wp-content\plugins\translatepress-multilingual\assets\lib\simplehtmldom\simple_html_dom.php on line 1432

When I disable the plugin the site runs well.

I cannot really delete the plugin and start over, because it remembers its settings after I delete it.

On the line of the error is this regular expression.

```
if (!preg_match("/^[\w-:]+$/", $tag)) {
        $node->_[TRP_HDOM_INFO_TEXT] = '<' . $tag . $this->copy_until('<>');
        if ($this->char === '<') {
            $this->link_nodes($node, false);
            return true;
        }

        if ($this->char === '>') $node->_[TRP_HDOM_INFO_TEXT] .= '>';
        $this->link_nodes($node, false);
        $this->char = (++$this->pos < $this->size) ? $this->doc[$this->pos] : null; // next
        return true;
    }
```

On the client site it is an error 500 internal server error.

The TranslatePress Support told me to use an add-on, which isn't helping at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If deleting the plugin is an option, all you need to do is remove the associated tables in your database after you remove the plugin.

Comment: I did that as well, but when I reinstall the plugin all setting and tables are there as they used to be.

Comment: Are you using a newer php version on your new server?

Comment: I am using php 7.3.1 at the moment

Comment: Can you share the old and new server specs? OS, PHP & MySQL ver?

Comment: On the local machine i am using xampp with php 5 or below.

The new server is a windows server 2019. Latest MySQL and PHP

Comment: Could you replace preg_match("/^[\w-:]+$/", $tag) with this one preg_match('/^([-\w\s])+$/i', $tag);

Comment: So I replaced it and the current error disappeared, but two other appeared.

Comment: PHP Warning:  preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 4 in C:\WebSites\wwwroot\scas_new\wp-content\plugins\translatepress-multilingual\assets\lib\simplehtmldom\simple_html_dom.php on line 664


Line 664: $pattern = "/([\w-:\*]*)(?:\#([\w-]+)|\.([\w-]+))?(?:\[@?(!?[\w-:]+)(?:([!*^$]?=)[\"']?(.*?)[\"']?)?\])?([\/, ]+)/is";
        preg_match_all($pattern, trim($selector_string) . ' ', $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

Comment: change it back and check if there's a new version of the plugin available. Other than that i wouldnt know what it could be.

Comment: Thank you Kevin for your help.

Comment: @Ivan-AsenOvedenski WP version is same on the new and old sites?

Comment: @KashifRafique Yes they are the same.

Comment: @Ivan-AsenOvedenski Seems to be a issue with the plugin and latest version of PHP. It would be better to ask the plugin developer here https://translatepress.com/support/